# Let a, b, c be integers. Is it true that gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,c) implies lcm(a,b)=lcm(a,c)?

Tags: number-theory

Let a, b, c be integers. Is it true that gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,c) implies lcm(a,b)=lcm(a,c)? Give reasoning for your answer.

Assume that the statement above is true.

We know that $gcd(a,b)*lcm(a,b)=ab$ and $gcd(a,c)*lcm(a,c)=ac$. We can assume that the lcm(a,c) and lcm(a,b) are nonzero because if not the the proof is trivial. Hence

$gcd(a,b)=\frac{ab}{lcm(a,b)}=\frac{ac}{lcm(a,c)}=gcd(a,c)$

Which can be reduce to

$\frac{b}{lcm(a,b)}=\frac{c}{lcm(a,c)}$

However the only way the equation above is true is if b=c. If not then the $lcm(a,c) \neq lcm(a,b)$

Comment: Based on your work so far, it sounds like you think it's false. Try coming up with a counterexample.

Comment: Take $a=4, b=6, c=10$.

Comment: Your sentence "Assume the statement $\dots$" is somewhat ambiguous. For all $a,b,c$? For  particular $a,b,c$? (That is what you intend.) The proof is fine, except for the somewhat mysterious lcm $0$ remark. However, you worked too hard, a single counterexample would have been enough. And the logic would have been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $gcd(2,3)=gcd(2,5)=1$.But $lcm(2,3)=6$ and $lcm(2,5)=10$.

Answer (score 0):

$a=24$ , 
$b=32$ , $ c=16$

$\gcd (24,32)=8$

$\gcd (24,16)=8$

$lcm (24,32)=96$

$lcm (24,16)=48$

$lcm (24,32)\ne lcm (24,16)$

Disproven by example

Answer (score 0):

One more counterexample, for people who (like me) prefer small numbers.  $a=b=1$ and $c=2$.